# 18.04 LTS install - Allocating resources problem message

Tags: 18.04, resource-limiting

I installed 18.04 LTS on my laptop and I get an 'Allocating resources problem' error message. Do I wait this out or is there something I must do?

Comment: Please let it boot and then run dmesg; capture its output, click [edit], and paste it into your question here. Please do not reply by way of [Add Comment] as when comments pile up, old comments get pushed off the screen. Also please turn your laptop upside down and get the model number off the serial # plate, and add that to your question as well; model names on the bezel or top are generally marketing series names and not as useful as the true model name.